# Output data to file using Isql sybase

Tags: sybase, isql

I am using below command to write data to csv file in isql

$ISQL -S DSA1_PROD -U emer_r_gh5432 -X

```
Query -

    Select * from SecDb..LoginOwnerTb where SvrId= 45566 and OwnerRitsId = '1001167635';
    OUTPUT TO '/tmp/sometable.csv' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE '';
    go
```

it says 
Server 'ABC', Line 1:
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I'm assuming you're working with Sybase ASE and the **isql** command line tool. There may be other ways to accomplish what you're trying to do when going against the SQLAnywhere, IQ and/or Advantage database products ... *shrug* ...

The `OUTPUT TO` clause is used with the **dbisql** GUI tool.

To perform a somewhat-similar `OUTPUT` operation with the **isql** command line tool:

```
-- once logged in via isql ...

-- to write to new file; to overwrite existing file:

select ....
go > /path/to/local/file/accessible/by/user/running/isql

-- to append to existing file:

select ...
go >> /path/to/local/file/accessible/by/user/running/isql
```

To set the column delimiter you can use the `-s` flag when invoking isql from the command line, eg:

```
# set the column delimiter to a semi-colon:
$ isql ... -s ';' ...

# set the column delimiter to a pipe:
$ isql ... -s '|' ...
```

Keep in mind that the output will still be generated using fixed-width columns, with each column's width determined by either a) the column's datatype 'width' or b) the column's title/label width, whichever is wider.

I'm not aware of any way to perform the following with the **isql** command line tool:

- designate a column delimiter on-the-fly while inside a isql session
- designate a `quote` character
- remove extra spaces (ie, ouput data in true delimited format as opposed to fixed-width format)

---

To generate true delimited files you have a few options:

- see if the **dbisql** GUI tool serves your purpose [I don't use **dbisql** so I'm *assuming* the `OUTPUT TO` clause works as expected]
- use the **bcp** (command line) utility to place the data into a delimited file [**bcp** options, and how to handle subsets of tables, is a much larger discussion, ie, too much to address in this response]
- see if you can find another (3rd party) tool that can extract the desired data set to a delimited file